# Wrong results for suming right side of List

Tags: c#, linq

During my exercises I receiving wrong Sum() for piece of code like below:

```
int right = arr.Where(v => arr.IndexOf(v) > i).Sum();
```

Can anyone explain me why this doesn't work?
Example:
List like this: {1, 2, 3, 3}
for i = 2 for left side:

```
int left = arr.Where(v => arr.IndexOf(v) < i).Sum();
```

returned 3,
but for right side of list Sum()=0
Why?

Answer (score 7):

Note that `IndexOf` returns the index of first occurrence of the element.
The problem is with your input list, in that you have two `3`s, so whenever the `IndexOf(3)` is evaluated the index returned is `2`, with condition `index > 2` obviously it is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

To use the actual index, there is a [different overload of Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where#System_Linq_Enumerable_Where__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32_System_Boolean__) that also uses the index.

An example from the linked page:

```
int[] numbers = { 0, 30, 20, 15, 90, 85, 40, 75 };

IEnumerable<int> query =
    numbers.Where((number, index) => number <= index * 10);

foreach (int number in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(number);
}
/*
 This code produces the following output:

 0
 20
 15
 40
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out this, problem is in statement

```
arr.IndexOf(v)
```

because `v = 3` two times and its return 2 both times. 
For you better to increment the index in loop or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know sums of left and right sides. The best would be to use .Skip() and .Take() because index of will return index of first occurence in the collection.

```
int right = arr.Skip(i).Sum();
int left = arr.Take(i).Sum(); // including the i-th element
```

For this case, the left would be 1+2=3 and right 3+3=6.